# Check if I have no messages in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, chat

I use this package: https://github.com/musonza/chat 
I have a function `inbox`:

```
public function inbox(Request $request) {
    $user = $this->user;
    //$conversations = Chat::commonConversations($user);
    //$LastMessages['partcipant'] = $conf->users[1];
    $conversations = Chat::conversations()->for($user)->limit(15)->page($request->page)->get();
    //dd($conversations); exit;
    //dd($conversations);
    $recipient = [];
    //dd($conversations);
    foreach($conversations as $conf) {
        $recipient[] = $conf->users()->where('user_id', '<>', $user->id)->first();
    }

    //dd($recipient);

    return view('inbox.index', compact('conversations', 'recipient'));
}
```

How I can check, if in conversation I no have messages? And if this is true, hide conversation in inbox. Now I have:

```
$conversations = Chat::conversations()->for($user)->limit(15)->page($request->page)->get();
```

When I clear conversation:

```
Chat::conversations($conversation)->for($user)->clear();
```

In inbox I have a conversation cleared, but I need hide cleared conversation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does $conversations return a collection as you are calling get()? If so then could you not utilize the [isEmpty](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-isempty)() function to check if the $conversations is the user has no messages?

So for instance, you could try:

```
$conversations = Chat::conversations()->for($user)->limit(15)->page($request->page)->get();

if ($conversations->isEmpty()) {
// this is an empty conversation and thus user has no messages
}
```